# Wagtail: How to remove summary items on the admin homepage

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am trying to remove/customize the summary items on the admin homepage with the recommended hook [`construct_homepage_summary_items`](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/hooks.html#construct-homepage-summary-items).

> Add or remove items from the ‘site summary’ bar on the admin homepage (which shows the number of pages and other object that exist on the site).

I manage to add my own items but struggle to remove all of the default items.

```
@hooks.register("construct_homepage_summary_items")
def add_my_summary_items(request, items):
    items.append(MySummaryItem(request))
    items.pop(0)
```

`items` only includes my custom items and `wagtail.admin.site_summary.PagesSummaryItem` but not those for images and documents. Removing items with `pop` doesn't seem to be as elegant as it could be either. I hoped for some way along the lines of the `construct_main_menu` hook:

```
menu_items[:] = [item for item in menu_items if item.name != 'explorer']
```

But I could not find a name identifier or an equivalent. How would I go on about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work? It should remove all summary items.

```
@hooks.register("construct_homepage_summary_items")
def remove_all_summary_items(request, items):
    items.clear()
```

## Update

If you need your hooks to run in a particular order, you can pass the order parameter.

```
@hooks.register('name_of_hook', order=1)  # This will run after every hook in the wagtail core
def my_hook_function(arg1, arg2...)
    # your code here
```

It seems that page item hook is executed before your hook and image and document items after. This surprises me as it would be logical that all Wagtail hooks are ran at the same time: before any custom code.

The order of apps has influence on the order of execution too.
Alternatively to the order param you can create a new app (named hooks?) and place it after Wagtail apps in INSTALLED_APPS. It only needs an `__init__.py` and `wagtail_hooks.py` file. The hooks in this app will execute after Wagtail hooks. Page, doc and image items are in items and can be removed.

```
from wagtail.core import hooks

@hooks.register("construct_homepage_summary_items")
def remove_all_summary_items(request, items):
    items.clear()
    items.append(YourSummaryItem)
```

Comment: Well, as I said I actually don't want to remove all summary items, just the default ones (i.e. pages, documents, images). But with the hook I can only `pop` the `PagesSummaryItem`. The other two defaults aren't in the `items` list and I don't understand where they come from.

Comment: This is a bug. FYI https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/6160

Comment: Thx for sticking with this and raising the issue on git. I went through the issue and actually @gasman hint about the order of executing did the trick (and makes your workaround obsolete, at least for me). Do you mind working gasmans answer into your answer – just the part with the ordering of hook execution? I am happy to accept it then.